# make the <select> tag selected display HTML

Tags: php, html, html-select

I'm trying to make appear some HTML code if the selected option is the right one, is it possible?

example:

```
<select name="ref_rubrique">
   <option value="1"> number 1 </option>
   <option value="2" selected> number 2 </option>
</select>
```

and

```
<?php if( $selected==true ): ?>
  <p>hello<p>
<?php else(): ?>
  <p><p>
<?php endif(); ?>
```

Comment: You're trying to do this with server-side code, which might not be the right approach at all.  When do you want this to happen?  While the page is rendering, immediately when the user makes the selection, or when the form posts to another page?

Comment: Hmmm.... Your PHP code looks pythonic. Or should I say, I have never tried it like that yet. But I too think you need the javascript approach for this problem your having.

Comment: @David Immediately when the user makes the selection would be perfect

Comment: @Touch Imma try the solution people gave me cause im really lost right here :(

Comment: @wlalele: In that case you'll want to try the answer below that involves JavaScript.  Since you want this to happen entirely on the client and not on the server then you can't use PHP to do it, you'll need to use JavaScript.  The answer below assumes using the jQuery library, which isn't necessary but can make the code a little simpler.

Comment: @David I just tryied this, and it didnt work cause when the user select an option, the selected argument isnt inserted in it (sorry for my english tryna do my best )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it that way if anyone is looking for my solution:

```
<select name="ref_rubrique" id="ref_rubrique">
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12" selected>12</option>
   <option value="13">13</option>
</select>
<div id="ref_output">
   <?php 
   if (isset($_GET["id_rubrique"])){
      if($_GET["id_rubrique"]==12){
   ?>
         <p>Your question here !</p>
         <p><input name="type" type="radio" value="1" <? if($page_type=='true'){ ?>checked<? } ?>>Oui<input name="type" type="radio" value="0" <? if($page_type=='false'){ ?>checked<? } ?>>Non</p>
   <?php
      }
   }
   ?>
</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   var selectElement = document.getElementById('ref_rubrique');
   var divElement = document.getElementById('ref_output');
   selectElement.onchange = function () {
   var selectedValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;
   if (selectedValue == '12') {
        divElement.style.display = "block";
   } else if (selectedValue != '12') {
        divElement.style.display = "none";
   }
};
</script>
```

Thanks to everyone for the help, bye :)

Answer (score 0):

When the form is submitted you can check `$_REQUEST['ref_rubrique']`.  You can then compare the value, e.g. `1 == $_REQUEST['ref_rubrique']`.  Both `"1"` and `"2"` are truthy values.

Comment: Thanks but I need it before the form is submitted if thats possible

Comment: @wlalele you need to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to happen immediately without refreshing the page, it needs to happen entirely in client-side code (JavaScript).  So, let's start with your page elements:

```
<select name="ref_rubrique">
    <option value="1"> number 1 </option>
    <option value="2" selected> number 2 </option>
</select>
```

You'll also need some sort of placeholder for the output.  And let's use `id` attributes so we can easily uniquely identify the elements in question.  So let's use this:

```
<select name="ref_rubrique" id="ref_rubrique">
    <option value="1"> number 1 </option>
    <option value="2" selected> number 2 </option>
</select>
<div id="ref_output"></div>
```

For now the output is empty.  It will be populated by our JavaScript code when the `select` element's value changes.  So now we need a `script` code block to attach that functionality to the `change` event of that element:

```
<select name="ref_rubrique" id="ref_rubrique">
    <option value="1"> number 1 </option>
    <option value="2" selected> number 2 </option>
</select>
<div id="ref_output"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var selectElement = document.getElementById('ref_rubrique');
    var divElement = document.getElementById('ref_output');

    selectElement.onchange = function () {
        var selectedValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;
        if (selectedValue == '1') {
            divElement.innerHTML = '<p>hello</p>';
        } else if (selectedValue == '2') {
            divElement.innerHTML = '<p></p>';
        }
    };

</script>
```

So what I've done here is:

- Get a reference to each of the HTML elements as JavaScript variables
- Bind a function to the `change` event for the `select` element, which will...
- Get a the selected value of the `select` element
- If that selected value is something, write HTML to the output `div` element
- If it's something else, write other HTML to the `div` element

You can see a live example of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aCb73/).

Answer (score -1):

You probably should use *id* better than *name*

```
<select id="ref_rubrique">
    <option value="1"> number 1 </option>
    <option value="2" selected> number 2 </option>
</select>
<div id="textPlace"></div>
```

You can use JQuery to check for the value that has been selected, then get the p or div element and add your text to it.

```
//check if the selected option has a value of 2, than set the text
if($('#ref_rubrique').val() == 2){
    $("#textPlace").html("My text");
}
```

Here is a live example: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/FsKqP/1/)

Comment: Thanks but I didnt find the way to make it work, im trying to display the html exactly when the user select the right thing in the dropdownlist

Comment: @wlalele, I added a live example