# How can I display option text on the dropdown menu that is different than the selected text?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

Using a simple `select`, I want to display one text on the dropdown list and another text in the select control after the option was selected. It's pretty similar to option's `label` attribute in its concept.

I'm not sure if it's even possible. Here's a **not-working** example:

```
<select>
  <option select-text="-- EMPTY --"> </option>
  <option select-text="YES!!!">Yes</option>
  <option>No</option>
</select>
```

---

**Update:** I didn't mention that I need to incorporate this solution in a generated HTML (ng-table filters), so any solution that is not pure HTML will be very hard to use. I even consider to look for another table control as a simpler solution, which is pretty basic - placeholder text in select filter.

I've created a question more specific to my problem:
[How can I put a placeholder text on ng-table select filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725612/how-can-i-put-a-placeholder-text-on-ng-table-select-filter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a relatively simple solution that relies on the standard `value` attribute and a custom `data-*` attribute:

```js
function showDisplayValue(e) {
  var options = e.target.options,
      option = e.target.selectedOptions[0],
      i;
  
  // reset options
  for (i = 0; i < options.length; ++i) {
    options[i].innerText = options[i].value;
  }
  
  // change the selected option's text to its `data-display` attribute value
  option.innerText = option.getAttribute('data-display');
}

document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('change', showDisplayValue, false);
```

```html
<select id="foo">
  <option data-display="*** BAR ***" value="Bar">Bar</option>
  <option data-display="*** BAZ ***" value="Baz">Baz</option>
  <option data-display="*** QUX ***" value="Qux">Qux</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Great solution, just with one bug - when reopening the dropdown the selected value is shown on the list with the asterisks.
Anyway, as you can see in my question update it still doesn't help me. It is the best answer to my original question so I'll probably mark it if nothing better will pop.

Comment: @HuBeZa, it would help if you could elaborate on the intention behind the desired behaviour.

Comment: You are right. Since the question changed significantly I've decided to create a new one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725612/how-can-i-put-a-placeholder-text-on-ng-table-select-filter

Answer (score 1):

Found something similar to what you're asking for here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19184179/6555780

It basically needs to be organised in javascript, so that the selected option shows immediately on the screen, the below code was taken from David's answer and can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/aCb73/

```
<select name="ref_rubrique" id="ref_rubrique">
    <option value="-- EMPTY --" selected> </option>
    <option value="YES!!!">Yes</option>
</select>
<div id="ref_output"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var selectElement = document.getElementById('ref_rubrique');
    var divElement = document.getElementById('ref_output');

    selectElement.onchange = function () {
        var selectedValue =     selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;
        if (selectedValue == '-- EMPTY --') {
            divElement.innerHTML = '<p>No</p>';
        } else if (selectedValue == 'YES!!!') {
            divElement.innerHTML = '<p>Yes</p>';
        }
    };

</script>
```

This basically targets the ref_rubique select tag and displays the code in the Javascript based on the selection (defaults as --EMPTY--)

Following our comments below, the following code could possibly help with ng-table:

```
  self.initialSorting = [
    { label: "Id ASC", value: { id: "asc"} },
    { label: "Id DESC", value: { id: "desc"} },
    { label: "Name ASC", value: { name: "asc"} },
    { label: "Name DESC", value: { name: "desc"} }
  ];
```

Comment: I couldn't made it work but it looks like a good idea (probably easier using JQuery).

Comment: Which bit isn't working? I put the above code in to jsfiddle and it seemed to work fine for me (it places the text outside of the select box inside the ref_output div)

Comment: Anyway it won't solve my problem since I need to incorporate this solution in a generated HTML (ng-table filters). I'm afraid it will take much more time than this feature diverse. I even consider to look for another table control as a simpler solution. Thanks anyway :っ)

Comment: If you could post more of your code above someone may be able to help with this further, looking at the ng-table docs, you could possibly change the javascript for ng-table to change the value and label in the select box, I've updated my answer with some of the code in the ng-table docs

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you want to print the text in select-text attribute. 
I've found this example if this is what you are looking for.

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option select-text="-- EMPTY --"> </option>
  <option select-text="YES!!!">Yes</option>
  <option>No</option>
</select>

$("#mySelect").change(function(){    
   $("#mySelect option:selected").text($("#mySelect").val());
});
```

This is where I found something similar.
[HTML select shows value instead of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699172/html-select-shows-value-instead-of-text)