# How can I put a placeholder text on ng-table select filter?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngtable

**Code sample:** https://plnkr.co/edit/hdYjHtEx1Dto1q6UVCS9

```
$scope.idFilter = {
    id: {
      id: "number",
      placeholder: "Filter by id", // Working
    }
  };

  $scope.nameFilter = {
    id: {
      id: "text",
      placeholder: "Filter by name", // Working
    }
  };

  $scope.statusFilter = {
    status: {
      id: "select",
      placeholder: "Filter by status", // Not working
    }
  };
```

It is easy to add a placeholder on a number or text filters in ngTable. However I could not manage to find a solution for select filter. I know that placeholder on a 'select' element is not trivial by itself, but it is achievable.

Can you find a solution for it in ngTable?
If not, can you recommend another table component that have this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add extra option in your select with `val:''` to simulate placeholder:

```
{
  id: '',
  title: 'Filter by Status'
}
```

And add default filter to refer *"Filter by Status"*

```
$scope.myTableParams = new NgTableParams({filter: { status: ""}}, {
    counts: [],
    dataset: users
});
```

**Result:** https://plnkr.co/edit/luaas1dExIuCYMa4WtN3?p=preview

---

**Update:** 
Add this CSS in order to distinct the placeholder look from other selections:

```
/* Set the select filter placeholder item look */
table.ng-table select.filter-select.ng-empty {
  color: gray;
}

/* Prevent select filter placeholder look to cascade to its options */
table.ng-table select.filter-select > option {
  color: #767676;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that answer my requirements. I just need to find out how to make the text to appear gray when this option is selected.

Comment: You can use css rules https://plnkr.co/edit/2kJ1pbs03xv3xGKV5a8S?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, I already find a solution which I think fits better. See the answer update.

Comment: Thank you for the example. Helped me heaps. The name filter has to be changed  in the plunker example to get the filtering for the name columns.
 
$scope.nameFilter = {
        name: { ..............

Answer (score 0):

Completing the @CMedina answer :

For multi and different select filters you can create another "statusFilter" object :

```
      $scope.statusFilter2 = {
        status2: {
          id: "select",
          placeholder: "Filter by status",
        }
      };
```

and then add it to the ngTableParams filter created before :

```
      $scope.myTableParams = new NgTableParams({filter: { status: "", status2: "" }}, {
        counts: [],
        dataset: users
      });
```

Don't forget to update your DOM.